# Hide one div and Show another div onclick

Tags: html, hide

I have two div's in which DIV 1 will be visible by default and if any user clicks on "Click me" link the DIV 1 should get hide and DIV 2 should get visible and after that i don't want to show DIV 1 on any click. DIV 1 should get hide permanently until the page gets refresh.

I worked on one code but i am not able to hide DIV 1 permanently.

Please have a look on this code.

```
<script>
function showDivs(start)
{
 var div;
 while((div = document.getElementById('div' + start)) !== false)
 {
  div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
  start ++;
 }
}
</script> 
<div class="expressBox"><div class="expressBtn"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="showDivs(1);" id="displayText">Click ME</a></div>
              <div class="txtStyle expressTxt" id="div1">Use saved addresses and payment options to expendite your purchase.</div>
              <div id="div2" style="display:none">
                <div class="existUserBox">
                  <div class="userHD"><strong>New User</strong></div>

                    <form name="ZB_ZipForm" action="$field{site_url_secure}/expresscheckout/index.html" method="post">
                    <div class="txtShipping">
                      <input type="text" size="13" maxlength="10" name="txt_zip" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" class="inputSpace" value="" />
                     <div class="clr"></div>
                      Required for Express Checkout</div>
                      <div class="btnSubmit">
                        <input type="image" name="btn_ExpressZip" src="$field{path_images}/global/btn-express-submit.png" />
                      </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="orDivider"><span>or</span></div>
                <div class="existUserBox">
                  <form name="ZB_LoginForm" action="$field{site_url_secure}/expresscheckout/login.html" method="post">
                    <div class="userHD"><strong>Existing User</strong></div>
                    <div class="txtShipping">
                      <input type="text" name="username" size="20" id="username"  placeholder="User Name" value="" class="inputSpace userSpace" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="txtShipping">
                      <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password" size="20" class="inputSpace userSpace nomargBott" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="reqExpChk"><a class="smallcolor" href="$field{site_url}/reminder/index.html" onMouseOver="status='Click for password help.'; return true;" onMouseOut="status=''; return true;">Forgot Password ?</a></div>
                    <div class="btnSubmit">
                      <input type="image" name="btn_Login" src="$field{path_images}/global/btn-express-submit.png" />
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

I Tried to find this kind of solution but didn't got any.
Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:**
if you are dealing with only two divs, you can directly make the change instead of using a loop
`document.getElementById('div1).style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('div2).style.display = 'block';`

**Case 2:**
if you are dealing with multiple divs, you can remove the div element from document
`var div = document.getElementById('div1');
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);`

**Case 3:**
if you are dealing with multiple divs and you don't want to remove the element permanently, then
`Use an array to store the id of div elements which are previously made invisible. Use the array everytime to make sure that divs in the array are not made visible again`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. If you can please provide me a working example what i required because i am not much good in javascript :(.

Comment: You have not mentioned what above described case you come under. To give you a simple solution. JUST CHANGE THE LINE `div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';`
 TO `(div.style.display == 'none') ? (div.style.display = 'block') : (div.parentNode.removeChild(div));`